# 3D Touch static shortcuts

Tags: ios, iphone, static, swift3, 3dtouch

Hey guys so my 3D touch shortcuts that I put in my info.plist show up but when I select them only the one that appears first in my code takes me to the view controller stated. The others just don't work (take me to the view I stated).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.amansk.software" {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        if shortcutItem.type == "com.amansk.hardware" {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hw")
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second **if statement** should be **OUTSIDE** of the first one

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.amansk.software" {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sw")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else if shortcutItem.type == "com.amansk.hardware" {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "hw")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

}